# How to remove space before \chapter

Tags: spacing, chapters

I am trying to customize the chapter style in the report class :

- Remove the blank page generated between chapter : Done with the 
  `etoolbox` package : `\patchcmd{\chapter}{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi}{}{}{}`
- Remove the "Chapter Number Something" : Done with the `titlesec` package : `\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\bfseries}}{}{0pt}{\Huge}`
- And here is where I am confused, when I want to remove the space before the chapter name.
  I tried with `titlesec` `\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}` but there is still space before the chaptername and I also tried with negative values in the second curly brackets but the text is writing other itself.

I would like the chapter name to be at the top of the page and not so much blank space for the other chapters before and after it.
If the top margin is set at 2.5cm, I would like the chatper name to be at 2.5cm

[image]

Here is my code :

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\chapter}{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge}

\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{-50pt}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\chapter{My chapter}
lol

\chapter{Another chapter}
lol

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You do not want  chapters to start on a new page?

Comment: Why not use `\sections` instead?

Comment: Bernard No, on the same page, the answer of schtandard works fine, thanks !
Andrew Swann I wanted to keep sections for further sectioning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you don't actually need to patch `\chapter`, since `openright` is not the default for `report`. If you use a document class where it is, you can use the option `openany` to prevent empty pages between chapters.

Now, there are several possibilities to tackle this:

---

You could use KOMA-Script, which provides many macros that allow an easier modification of the layout than the standard classes:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

% makes the page borders visible
\usepackage{showframe}

\renewcommand*\chapterformat{}
\renewcommand*\chapterheadstartvskip{}

\begin{document}

\chapter{My chapter}
lol

\chapter{Another chapter}
lol


\end{document}
```

[image: First MWE output]

---

If you prefer working with `report` and `titlesec`, the correct syntax of `\titlespacing` is

```
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{*0}{*0}
```

or

```
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
```

To get rid of some of the space above the chapter title, you can drop the `display` option of `\titleformat`. I did however not manage to get rid of all the space without some hacking of internal commands. If we do that, we can just as well do it without `titlesec`:

---

You could redefine `\@makechapterhead` which typesets the chapter title. Here I took the default definition and commented everything you don't want.

```
\documentclass{report}

% makes the page borders visible
\usepackage{showframe}

\makeatletter
    \renewcommand*\@makechapterhead[1]{%
%       \vspace*{50\p@}%
        {%
            \parindent\z@\raggedright\normalfont
%           \ifnum\c@secnumdepth>\m@ne
%               \huge\bfseries\@chapapp\space\thechapter\par
%               \nobreak\vskip 20\p@
%           \fi
%           \interlinepenalty\@M
            \Huge\bfseries
            #1\par
            \nobreak\vskip 40\p@
        }
    }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{My chapter}
lol

\chapter{Another chapter}
lol

\end{document}
```

[image: Second MWE output]

Comment: Mmh it worked fine by redefining `\@makechapterhead`
I didn't have a look at the other possibilities yet
Thanks for the quick answer !

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the patch is meant to do: its main effect is that no page break will happen when a `\chapter` begins.

No blank page will ever appear with the `report` class, unless you pass it the `openright` option.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\bfseries\Huge}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {}

\titlespacing{\chapter}
  {0pt}
  {-50pt}
  {0pt}

\begin{document}

\chapter{My chapter}

\lipsum[1-5]

\chapter{Another chapter}

\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am trying to generate a document with verso figures and recto text. I tried to keep this format when using `\chapter`

Comment: I am curious that how did you know the space before the chapter title is 50pt.

Comment: @Y.zeng With some experience, I learned how to read the code in `book.cls` 

Comment: Okay, so excellent! Is there a command that can eliminate the space without knowing the exact value of itself?

Comment: @Y.zeng No. In an ideal world that value should be a parameter, but when `book.cls` was written resources were scarce, so it is hardwired.

Comment: Okay. I will remember this.